# TACO - MacInCloud - Secure connection to https://###.###.###.###:3000/cordova could not be established

Tags: ios, cordova, taco

I'm trying to build using taco remotebuild within on MacInCloud. I've been able to get it to run on another Mac before but can't get it to work there.

Fails after a minute or two when I try to do a build. Looks like it either fails during the process of uploading the tar or just after that. Failed on both secure and non secure modes.

Any ideas on what to look for?

**VS Output Window shows this**:

1>  ------ Submitting new build request to: https://###.###.###.###:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.3.3&cfg=release&options=--device&loglevel=warn

1>MDAVSCLI : error : Secure connection to https://###.###.###.###:3000/cordova could not be established. Verify that the build server is running in secure mode.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**Mac terminal output shows this**:

GET /certs/529267 200 16.344 ms - 4298
GET /modules/taco-remote 200 6.085 ms - 7
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.3.3&cfg=release&options=--device&loglevel=warn
{"accept-language":"en-US","host":"###.###.###.###:3000","connection":"close","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}

Downloading: taco-remote-multiplexer
taco-remote-multiplexer@1.2.8 node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer
└── semver@4.3.4

taco-remote-multiplexer downloaded and installed.
Build will be executed under: /Users/user901146/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/6771
Saving build request payload to : /Users/user901146/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/6771
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.3.3&cfg=release&options=--device&loglevel=warn - - ms - -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I figured this out. Had an inkling it was some kind of network issue, tried it on another network (tethered to my phone) and it worked. Perhaps my isp is in some way blocking port 3000. Which is weird because it is clearly communicating with the remote build server before it times out.

Anyway, if anyone else runs into that. Look into network problems.